# Zooming image after plotting a point in android

Tags: android

I have made an app that plots a point on the image where I click. Now I want to add pinch zoom in and zoom out and drag functionality. What is the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance
This is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RelativeLayout rl_Main;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rl_Main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        rl_Main.addView(new MyView(this));

    }

    class MyView extends View{


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Point point = new Point();
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
              Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.josepg);
              canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, paint);
              canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 1, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                point.x = event.getX();
                point.y = event.getY();

            }
              invalidate();
            return true;

        }

    }
     class Point {
            float x, y;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Greg, this is quite complicated so if you're happy to use a library to do it, try the demo of mine here and see if it does what you want: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for your reply. Your demo looks good. But how do I use your library in my project.

Comment: I copied your sample project into eclipse. All the classes are working except Extension and animation. I keep getting the exception  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagezoomplot/com.example.imagezoomplot.extension.ExtensionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample.extension.views.PinView